# Can multitable Insert statement combine columns from view and columns from another view?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm planning to do SQL expert examination.
I have doubts that answer D is correct:

> Evaluate the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
  ( employee_id NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY
  , last_name VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
  , department_id NUMBER(2)NOT NULL
  , job_id VARCHAR2(8)
  , salary NUMBER(10,2));
```

> You issue
>   the following command to create a view that displays the IDs and last
>   names of the sales staff in the organization:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW sales_staff_vu AS
SELECT employee_id, last_name,job_id
FROM employees
WHERE job_id LIKE 'SA_%'
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

> Which two statements are true regarding the above view? (Choose two.)
>
> A. It allows you to insert rows into the EMPLOYEES table .
>
> B. It allows you to delete details of the existing sales staff from
>   the EMPLOYEES table.
>
> C. It allows you to update job IDs of the existing sales staff to any
>   other job ID in the EMPLOYEES table.
>
> D. It allows you to insert IDs, last names, and job IDs of the sales
>   staff from the view if it is used in multitable INSERT statements.

[Source](http://www.aiotestking.com/oracle/2011/09/which-two-statements-are-true-regarding-the-above-view/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge answer D is wrong.Reasons are

1.If A is wrong, definitely D is wrong.because `department_id` column is mandatory field on the table, but it is not mentioned in view.so we can't insert a row using this view.

2.In Answer D,multitable INSERT statements are `INSERT ALL`, `INSERT FIRST`,etc.

to check this Answer,i have tried these steps

```
CREATE TABLE employees123
  ( employee_id NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY
  , last_name VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
  , department_id NUMBER(2)NOT NULL
  , job_id VARCHAR2(8)
  , salary NUMBER(10,2));
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW sales_staff_vu123 AS
SELECT employee_id, last_name,job_id,department_id
FROM employees123
WHERE job_id LIKE 'SA_%'
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

--`department_id` is added to view

---

--here i am trying to insert my employees table rows to employees123 table

```
INSERT ALL
         INTO sales_staff_vu123 --using View

  SELECT employee_id, last_name,job_id,department_id
  FROM   employees;
```

---

Error at Command Line:153 Column:15
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01702: a view is not appropriate here
01702. 00000 -  "a view is not appropriate here"
*Cause:
*Action:

So my decision is **we cant use views with multitable insert statements.**

Answer (score 1):

A is FALSE as the view doesn't allow inserting into the `department_id` column which is mandatory.

B is TRUE, although it would be more accurate to say that the view only allows deletions of employees where the `job_id` matches the predicate `LIKE 'SA_%'`.

C is FALSE, as the `WITH CHECK OPTION` means that you can't change the job_id if the new job_id doesn't match the view's predicate.

D is **FALSE**: a multitable insert statement can't just insert some columns into the view and the remaining columns into the employees table. Even if you join the view to the table, the insert must still insert into the base table, not into the view:

```
insert into
(select e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id, e.job_id
 from   sales_staff_vu v
 join   employees e
 on     v.employee_id = e.employee_id)
values
(1, 'KEMP', 2, 'SA_X');
```

I suspect this is a test of your ability to verify and ignore wrong information on the internet - i.e. 99% of sites say D is true!

Now, my answer can be easily disproved by crafting a multitable insert statement that successfully inserts *via the view*.

Comment: I would rather understand D as: we can take mentioned view, join it to some other table, take `IDs, last names, and job IDs` from it and insert it to some other table. Then D is `TRUE`. Although I may be wrong as English is not my native language.

Comment: Answer D is not very clear to me either, even as an English speaker. The proviso "if it is used in multitable INSERT statements" implies strongly that inserts *cannot* be done for single table insert statements; but this is patently false, so answer D is still false, in my view.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey for the support..:)